# R for() loop to check if a number is between two others and add an ID

Tags: r

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

I have two separate data frames in R, one with a start and end number, the second with a middle number.  Included here is a mock data set illustrating my conundrum.

The data table with two numbers also has a GroupID as seen here.

```
TwoNum <- structure(list(GroupID = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Clstr001", 
"Clstr002", "Clstr007", "Clstr008", "Clstr010", "Clstr011", "Clstr015", 
"Clstr016", "Clstr017", "Clstr018"), class = "factor"), StartNum = c(2L, 
5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 41L, 67L, 70L, 73L, 78L), EndNum = c(4L, 7L, 
25L, 27L, 40L, 43L, 68L, 72L, 75L, 80L)), .Names = c("GroupID", 
"StartNum", "EndNum"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

head(TwoNum)
```

Here is the date table with a single number

```
OneNum <- structure(list(GroupID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), MiddleNum = c(3L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 24L, 25L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 42L, 67L, 71L, 73L, 74L, 
75L, 78L, 79L, 80L)), .Names = c("GroupID", "MiddleNum"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))  

head(OneNum)
```

When the MiddleNum is between the StartNum and EndNum I am trying to replace the NA with the corresponding GroupID - i.e. replace the NA with the GroupID row that brackets the middle number.

My real data set is substantially longer and I am thus trying to build this into a `for()` loop that checks if the Middle number is between ANY (i.e. all rows) of the Start and End pairs and if yes, adds the corresponding GroupID to the OneNum data frame.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am not necessarily looking for someone to create the entire loop (but would not turn that down either...), but new ideas would help greatly.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with equal values (i.e. when the MiddleNum equal a StartNum)?

Comment: Do they have the same number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some base R that tackles the problem. This won't be terribly fast for very large datasets but it won't run into memory issues if the ranges of StartNum and EndNum get large. Also, this does what you literally requested and handles situations where the value doesn't fall in between with an NA. If you don't care what happens when it fails or it's impossible to completely fail (every values is categorized) then you can leave out the the `if` statement. You can modify this to use `<=` where necessary.

```
ids <- as.character(TwoNum$GroupID)
f <- function(x){
    a <- ids[ (TwoNum$StartNum < x) & (x < TwoNum$EndNum) ]
    if (length(a) == 0) NA else a
    }       
OneNum$GroupID <- lapply(OneNum$MiddleNum, f)
```

If you actually have all of the possible ranges covered and every single MiddleNum will be labelled then you only need one side of the points and there is already a function to do this in R. In this case I'm including numbers equal to the endpoints.

```
cut(OneNum$MiddleNum, breaks = c(2, TwoNum$EndNum), labels = TwoNum$GroupID, include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hey John Thanks for the suggestions! This works well with the sample data on the post and I am trying to change the code to accommodate my real data but am getting an error pertaining to the breaks argument.  Why did you use 2?  Reading the '?cut' help file any number less than the first MidNum should be OK to initiate the cuts.  Also, do you have any suggestions on how to 'cbind()' (or otherwise attach) the output of factors from your code to the OneNum data?

Comment: When you assign something to a variable that doesn't exist in a `data.frame` it gets created so `OneNum$NewID <- cut...`. But you already have an old variable in OneNum that you can just change so it would be `OneNum$GroupID <- cut(...`. As for your error, it would be great if you showed what the error was. The breaks argument needs one more item than the labels. The first item is the start and then every other item is an end point.

Comment: My error message is 'Error in cut.default(ColoLocs$DateTimeNumber, breaks = c(2, ColoClstr$LastClstrNumTime), :'breaks' are not unique' Although because I am testing your code with my data, the objects are not named the same. Nonetheless, these objects represent the OneNum$MiddleNum and TwoNum$EndNum respectively. I have also tried replacing "2" from the breaks argument with '40603.92' the lowest of the actual 'MidNumbers.' Notice my real numbers are not whole integers.  Also, what is the best way to post larger data sets so I can better reflect my actual data? Thanks for the continued help!

Comment: Your error tells you that your breaks are not all unique. See the help on `cut`. It's Ok that they're floats but they have to all be different ones. `length(ColoClstr$LastClstrNumTime)` must equal `length(unique(ColoClstr$LastClstrNumTime))`. Also, from the help, `ColoClstr` must be sorted on the end time because `cut` will sort the breaks. There are a variety of ways to handle large data sets. A link to a Google doc works.

Comment: FYI John, I have created a new post after incorporating your earlier comments and a better data set.  Your continued advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is posted under the title R Find middle number and add ID in data.table() and cut() FYI

Comment: @John your function piece works perfect for me when using date time and POSIXct. however the code seems to return a list? see str(OneNum) with above code/dataframes. Is it possible to just return a numeric value not in a list?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `data.table` package -

```
TwoNum <- data.table(TwoNum)
OneNum <- data.table(OneNum)
OneNum[, GroupID := NULL]

TwoNum <- TwoNum[,MiddleNum := StartNum]

setkey(TwoNum, MiddleNum)
setkey(OneNum, MiddleNum)

TwoNum[OneNum, roll = Inf]
```

The `roll = Inf` basically allows a closest match sort of merge. Your problem might have more cases (multiple matches for the same MiddleNum, MiddleNum outside all ranges, etc.) and I'd suggest playing around with this a little so that you're sure it works.

Output

```
> TwoNum[OneNum, roll = Inf]
    MiddleNum  GroupID StartNum EndNum
 1:         3 Clstr001        2      4
 2:         5 Clstr002        5      7
 3:         6 Clstr002        5      7
 4:         7 Clstr002        5      7
 5:        24 Clstr007       23     25
 6:        25 Clstr007       23     25
 7:        33 Clstr010       32     40
 8:        34 Clstr010       32     40
 9:        35 Clstr010       32     40
10:        37 Clstr010       32     40
11:        42 Clstr011       41     43
12:        67 Clstr015       67     68
13:        71 Clstr016       70     72
14:        73 Clstr017       73     75
15:        74 Clstr017       73     75
16:        75 Clstr017       73     75
17:        78 Clstr018       78     80
18:        79 Clstr018       78     80
19:        80 Clstr018       78     80
```